# Asymmetrical background shadow on CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a background effect on CSS, currently I am only using a background image shaped like the example:

[image: Background image]

But I think there must be a way to do this effect on CSS, I have been looking for this for too long and I can't really find the right answer anywhere, is there a way to do this?

so what I need is an assymetrical background for the container that is done with CSS.

Comment: CSS Transforms ... sKew

Comment: Try This - http://jsfiddle.net/qgsnb0or/

Comment: That is very close to what I am looking for, can you post it as an answer, I think that did it

Comment: You could also use clip or before and after with rotation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this by using css [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qgsnb0or/)**

```css
body {
    background:url('http://thumbs.xdesktopwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11-1/Drops-On-Green-Background-720x405.jpg')
}
div {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(15deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(15deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(15deg);
    display: table;
    padding: 0 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-15deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus vestibulum elementum. Vivamus feugiat diam eget aliquet fringilla. Nullam et ex id dui malesuada bibendum. Duis interdum pharetra nibh sit amet lacinia. Sed sit amet fermentum diam. Nulla euismod libero nibh, ac volutpat nulla luctus vitae. Nulla sit amet lectus odio.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great JSFiddle, can you show us how to un-skew the text?

Comment: That's what I was going to ask, I would like to un-skew the text

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/mkt27ug1/

Comment: This helps smooth the jagged edges in Firefox - outline: 1px solid transparent;, and the browser support table:http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d